# Oracle Query: Picking the last change in data in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has the following columns:

Product_ID    Pricing_Date  Current_Price  Last_Pricing_Date

I am trying to write a query that shows the old price (Last_Price) of the product before it was changed to the current price so that my results look like the below

```
PRODUCT_ID  PRICE_DATE  PRODUCT_PRICE LAST_PRICE
BlueLotion  24/08/2018   £10.00        £7.50
BlueLotion  23/08/2018   £10.00        £7.50
BlueLotion  22/08/2018   £10.00        £7.50
BlueLotion  21/08/2018   £7.50         £6.50 
BlueLotion  20/08/2018   £7.50         £6.50 
BlueLotion  19/08/2018   £7.50         £6.50
BlueLotion  17/08/2018   £6.50         £7.50
BlueLotion  16/08/2018   £6.50         £7.50
BlueLotion  13/08/2018   £6.50         £7.50
BlueLotion  12/08/2018   £7.50          NULL
BlueLotion  11/08/2018   £7.50          NULL
BlueLotion  10/08/2018   £7.50          NULL
```

Effectively picking what the value of the data was before the change.
Some resources to test - you can quickly create a table using script:

```
create table COMP_RESULTS (product_id varchar2(20), price_date date, product_price number);

insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','24 AUG 2018','10');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','23 AUG 2018','10');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','22 AUG 2018','10');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','21 AUG 2018','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','20 AUG 2018','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','19 AUG 2018','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','18 AUG 2018','6.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','17 AUG 2018','6.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','16 AUG 2018','6.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','15 AUG 2018','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','14 AUG 2018','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion','13 AUG 2018','7.5');
```

I'm sorry everyone, can I add one other complication. I need to also bring a column into the results table that shows the Last_Date_With_Prev_Price 
The final results set would therefore be

```
PRODUCT_ID  PRICE_DATE  PRICE  LAST_PRICE  DATE_WITH_PREV_RATE
BlueLotion  24/08/2018  £10.00  £7.50       21/08/2018
BlueLotion  23/08/2018  £10.00  £7.50       21/08/2018
BlueLotion  22/08/2018  £10.00  £7.50       21/08/2018
BlueLotion  21/08/2018  £7.50   £6.50       17/08/2018
BlueLotion  20/08/2018  £7.50   £6.50       17/08/2018
BlueLotion  19/08/2018  £7.50   £6.50       17/08/2018
BlueLotion  17/08/2018  £6.50   £7.50       12/08/2018
BlueLotion  16/08/2018  £6.50   £7.50       12/08/2018
BlueLotion  13/08/2018  £6.50   £7.50       12/08/2018
BlueLotion  12/08/2018  £7.50   NULL        NULL
BlueLotion  11/08/2018  £7.50   NULL        NULL
BlueLotion  10/08/2018  £7.50   NULL        NULL
```

Comment: On a sidenote: don't use strings instead of dates. The conversion to a date may or may not work depending on session settings. Use ANSI date literals such as `DATE '2018-08-24'`. And don't use strings instead of numbers for the same reason and others. `'7.5'` may be convertable into a number or not, depending on the session setting for the decimal separator. `'7.500'` can mean 7.5 for one user and 7,500 for another.

Comment: At first you say the table includes a column `Last_Pricing_Date`, but your sample table doesn't have that column.  If that column exists and means what I think it does, this could be done with a self-join.

Comment: @DaveCosta The table does not have the Last Pricing Date (a mistake on my part when writing the question - hence the question, otherwise I agree this would have been pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight-forward approach to this is a subquery in the select clause:

```
select
  product_id,
  price_date,
  product_price,
  (
    select
      max(before.product_price) keep (dense_rank last order by before.price_date)
    from comp_results before
    where before.product_id = comp_results.product_id
      and before.price_date < comp_results.price_date
      and before.product_price <> comp_results.product_price
  ) as last_price
from comp_results
order by product_id, price_date desc;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HTBXE60602

Comment: Amazing, have applied this to a marketdata database. Q. can you explain how the dense_rank function works

Comment: It would be interesting to see what it would look like if you are trying to get something like the previous credit rating which is a varchar and you can't use analytical functions on.

Comment: The `keep (dense_rank last order by before.price_date)` orders the records by date and then takes the records for the last date. This is probably only one in your table (one price per product and day only). In case of ties, it would grab the higher price (`max(before.product_price)`).

Comment: First of all there is no analytic function used. (We call window functions analytic, as they give additional information on the already selected data set.) See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174. Then, why do you think you can't use them on strings? You can get the maximum, minimum, etc. If you are talking about some order of, say, GOOD, MEDIUM, BAD, then you should have a table containing those strings along with a sortkey, so we can read from the table that GOOD is better than MEDIUM and MEDIUM is better than BAD.

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky because your prices go up and down.  You can use `lag(ignore nulls)`.  First, find when the price changes.  Then get the previous price.  So:

```
select cr.*,
       (case when prev_current_price <> current_price
             then prev_current_price  -- use the previous price when it changes
             else  -- lag to the previous change
                  lag( (case when prev_current_price <> current_price then prev_current_price
                        end) ignore nulls
                      ) over (partition by cr.product_id
                              order by cr.price_date
                             )
        end) as prev_price
from (select cr.*,
             lag(cr.current_price) over (partition by cr.product_id order by cr.price_date) as prev_current_price
      from comp_results cr
     ) cr;
```

Comment: This does not quite work as the previous prices are shifted down one row from the OP's expected results. [SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa924/8)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I have a follow on question. I need to produce another results column that shows the Last_Date_With_Previous_Price.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I used your proposed solution and it worked but having trouble with the extra part - would you mind looking at the modified part of the question to see if the extra column can be pulled?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the analytic functions `LEAD` and `LAG` (with the `IGNORE NULLS` option) like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa924/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table COMP_RESULTS (product_id varchar2(20), price_date date, product_price number);

insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-24','10');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-23','10');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-22','10');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-21','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-20','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-19','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-18','6.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-17','6.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-16','6.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-15','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-14','7.5');
insert into comp_results values ('BlueLotion',DATE '2018-08-13','7.5');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT product_id,
       price_date,
       product_price,
       LAG( prev_price ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY price_date ) AS prev_price
FROM   (
SELECT c.*,
       CASE product_price
       WHEN LEAD( product_price ) OVER ( PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY price_date )
       THEN NULL
       ELSE product_price
       END AS prev_price
FROM   comp_results c
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa924/5/0)**:

```
| PRODUCT_ID |           PRICE_DATE | PRODUCT_PRICE | PREV_PRICE |
|------------|----------------------|---------------|------------|
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-13T00:00:00Z |           7.5 |     (null) |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-14T00:00:00Z |           7.5 |     (null) |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-15T00:00:00Z |           7.5 |     (null) |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-16T00:00:00Z |           6.5 |        7.5 |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-17T00:00:00Z |           6.5 |        7.5 |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-18T00:00:00Z |           6.5 |        7.5 |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-19T00:00:00Z |           7.5 |        6.5 |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-20T00:00:00Z |           7.5 |        6.5 |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-21T00:00:00Z |           7.5 |        6.5 |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-22T00:00:00Z |            10 |        7.5 |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-23T00:00:00Z |            10 |        7.5 |
| BlueLotion | 2018-08-24T00:00:00Z |            10 |        7.5 |
```

Comment: Thats a really good answer, thank you for that. I have a follow on question - it also works when there are multiple products for example GreenLotion is also in the mix. Perfect, thank you!